# Netbeans refuses to shutdown

Tags: netbeans, shutdown

An infuriating problem. 
My Netbeans IDE 7.2 refuses to shutdown when I try to shutdown my machine.

I have got to use task manager to close the beast.

Its a windows 7 64 bit machine.

I have tried the usual Netbeans forums. 
Any Ideas?

PS: I also use the well behaved Eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps it's waiting for an application server or another external tool to shut down.

Comment: Checked that, but no. Its one of the last processes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to 7.3 and I no longer have a problem. 
BTW Netbeans 7.3 is great for developing HTML 5 code.

Answer (score 0):

from what I'm seeing, you might have a corrupted install of netbeans cause usually it is light on a system. How long ago did you install it? Did you make any major changes before this all started, from evinvorment setting changes to major changes like how the thing complies etc...? I would say, the easiest bet is to back up the settings, if possible, and reinstall or do a repair install, if offered, of netbeans.